# Is the WoW experience fundamentally different if I've started playing in 2014?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just bought the game yesterday and started playing for the first time. I have all the expansions up to Mists of Pandaria included by default. What I can't understand is whether things are different for me right from the get-go because of events in the expansion packs.

For example, a certain town called Auberdine was supposed to be a questing location for my night elf druid character, but for me that town is destroyed as a result of events from Cataclysm and I instead quest at a nearby town on the coast named Lor'danel.

I am playing basically the same quests, regardless of the superficial changes, right? Given that I have not "experienced" the plot of the expansions yet, it is confusing that I can see their effects already on the world, because I'm not there yet in the story.

Also, this also means that, in this case, there is literally no way now for me to ever experience the original Auberdine, the way it was before the expansions, right? I, and every other new person will always be sent to that other town instead.

How this works out in World of Warcraft is confusing to me and I was hoping someone can offer some perspective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. Completely different experiences. Quests are created and destroyed to fit the story, and you will never see the original Auberdine (unless they add a time machine or something).

As for being confused, [this](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/game/the-story-of-warcraft/chapter1) website should explain everything.

Comment: thanks, I've played Reign Of Chaos and The Frozen Throne so I'm not totally out of the loop. So you're saying I will see effects of expansions prematurely here and there but I can still play out the complete "plot" in sequence, right?

Comment: @ankit Kind of - some of the quests will remain the same, but the "main" quest line is always changing. Every major patch, it changes, and there's a new problem for the heroes of Azeroth to deal with.

Comment: @ankit Regular WoW didn't have a major antagonist in it. End game started with dungeons and then went to a few 20 and 40-man raids that were unrelated to each other (Ragnaros, Onyxia, Hakkar, Blackwing, Kel'thuzad, and then the two Ahn'Qiraj bosses).  It wasn't until 60-70 where you finally had a single (then pair) of enemies you were dealing with.

Comment: Burning Crusade started off with Illidan but moved on the Kael'thas Sunstrider (The Blood Elf leader). Wrath of the Lich King had The Lich King.  Cataclysm had Deathwing.  Mists of Pandaria dealt with corruption and ended up with Warchief Garrosh as its last boss (this was heavily foreshadowed since Cataclysm)... and at the start of Warlords of Draenor, you're chasing him down again after his escape.

Comment: Having said ALL that, the 1-60 zones are post-Cataclysm and have been completely changed (except Silithus) to match the technology used in Cataclysm.  Which makes Burning Crusader (60-70) content look extremely dated in comparison now.

Comment: @Powerlord Vanilla WoW didn't have a specific antagonist, but that was also the point. The world was beset on all sides by many threats, which were not all related to each other. The heroes basically traveled the world trying fighting general evil. Though by the same token, Deathwing did turn out to be behind a great many of those threats.